# Word order with the verb "demeurer": Which noun to use as the subject?

Tags: ordre-des-mots, inversion

I'm translating some English sentences into French:

> Elle peut trouver toutes les excuses qu’elle veut pour justifier son déménagement, elle doit avouer que **la raison** principale **demeure** **son échec** à intégrer l'école de son choix.

I wonder which noun is better suited as the subject of this "demeurer" clause: "la raison" or "son échec"? Should it be the other way round:

> ... elle doit avouer que **son échec** à intégrer l'école de son choix **demeure  la raison** principale.

On another note: Is the construction "la raison principale demeure son échec ..." considered an inversion?

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is missing a pronoun to work:

> ...elle doit avouer que son échec à intégrer l'école de son choix **en** demeure la raison principale.